# How to make query WebSQL not minus?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, web-sql

My code :

```
function decrementCart(quantity, id){
                    db.transaction(function(tx){
                        tx.executeSql("UPDATE cart SET quantity=(quantity -1) WHERE id=?", [id])
                    });
                }
```

How to make the quantity not minus? i try to click button for my function then my quantity after 0 is -1. Can you help me?

Comment: is this reason `quantity -1`?

Comment: it's to reduce sum of quantity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your code login you can put validation to check quantity should not `-1` before update to db

```
function decrementCart(quantity, id){
                    if(quantity > 0){
                        db.transaction(function(tx){
                            tx.executeSql("UPDATE cart SET quantity=(quantity -1) WHERE id=?", [id])
                        });
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change your query to

```
"UPDATE cart SET quantity=IF(quantity>0, quantity-1, 0) WHERE id=?"
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer sir, but not work for my code hehe

Comment: I see my quantity not reduce if i use your query sir.